# PHP POST data via command line

Tags: php, html, http

You can run a php script from command line by this: `php youscript.php`
My question: Is it possible to pass the post data to the script like `php yourscript.sh post1=test post2=test2` so that you can get this data by `$_POST["post1"]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php

Example #1 getopt() example: The basics

```
<?php
// Script example.php
$options = getopt("f:hp:");
var_dump($options);
?>
```

`shell> php example.php -fvalue -h`

```
array(2) {
  ["f"]=>
  string(5) "value"
  ["h"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

---

`$_POST` is set by Apache, which gets `$_POST` data from a HTTP connection. If you're looking to call php directly via the command line, apache is never called and hence $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST etc, these are never set.